# What's the meaning of this callback parameter in tribute.js?

Tags: javascript, callback, frontend

New to js. I am developing a personal site which uses [tribute.js](https://github.com/zurb/tribute#loading-remote-data) to have an @mention feature. In my case, I need to retrieve the mention list from a remote server. The [official document](https://github.com/zurb/tribute#loading-remote-data) gives an example to implement it. The thing confusing me is the meaning of `cb` parameter which is not even defined in anywhere. Could anyone help to explain it?

```
{
  //..other config options
  // function retrieving an array of objects
  values: function (text, cb) { 
    remoteSearch(text, users => cb(users));
  },
  lookup: 'name',
  fillAttr: 'name'
}
// ajax
function remoteSearch(text, cb) {
  var URL = "YOUR DATA ENDPOINT";
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        cb(data);
      } else if (xhr.status === 403) {
        cb([]);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", URL + "?q=" + text, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Meaning is hiding in the title of your question, `cb` means callback :)

It gets called by the `remoteSearch` function which in its turn was called with `cb` parameter passed by the tribute.js engine.

Comment: After more learning, I now understand its semantics. Thanks!